# Flex Mobile: Swipe gesture working as the native one

Tags: apache-flex, mobile, air, gesture

I'm using a ViewNavigator with a SlideViewTransition (moving horizontally) to replace each view any time the user swipes the screen.

That's OK, it's working but I need to make it work like the native one:
- If you stop the swipe in the middle and you want to return, the view follow your finger.
- Some elastic effects (I don't think it can be possible this one)

Thanks!

UPDATE: The code is something like this. Is the regular swipe with a barebone view component.

```
var slideTransLeft:SlideViewTransition = new SlideViewTransition();
            slideTransLeft.direction = ViewTransitionDirection.LEFT;
            slideTransLeft.duration = 600;


var slideTransRight:SlideViewTransition = new SlideViewTransition();
            slideTransRight.direction = ViewTransitionDirection.RIGHT;
            slideTransRight.duration = 600;

addEventListener(TransformGestureEvent.GESTURE_SWIPE,onSwipe);

function onSwipe(event:TransformGestureEvent):void
{
 if (event.offsetX == 1) {
   navigator.pushView(myNewViewClass,null,null,slideTransRight);
 }
 else if (event.offsetX == -1) {
   navigator.popView(slideTransLeft);
 }
}
```

Comment: Can you share some code?  When do you trigger the transition?  Are you using default Flex transitions?  Can't you specify the elastic properties 'elastic' via some type of easing function?

Comment: I added some code now. With elastic, I mean something that follows your finger. With the gesture and the transition of the view is not actually integrated, it just listen to the gesture, not the position of the fingers. So, is there a third party component or something that do a better job than the actual View Flex component?